# How to create a terminal like scene in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a terminal for my unity game. I can create a text field and an input field separately, using the method found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtbNDTMqsbg . 
Unfortunately this doesn't feel like a terminal at all. I would like it to write to the same window. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I see plenty of methods to do it. One of them is actually making two windows (input and output) but visually just make them seamless, so no one will see two fields. Anyway this question is to broad.

Comment: Wait, this question isn't broad. I have already done something like this but what I would like to do is input a "command" and have it print the result below it. Literally like a bash terminal. Having a seamless combination doesn't emulate this behavior.

Comment: In bash terminal when you enter command the result goes above not below.  At least mine on osx and the ones I was using on linux few years ago.

Comment: What? Look at this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Linux_command-line._Bash._GNOME_Terminal._screenshot.png .
The command ls is run and the result is spit out just bellow it.

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is the result of finished process is printed above. When process is runing it goes below, you are right. If you want it to go below too then this combination isnt good. Truth.